# Is it possible in terminal to set color for specific filetypes?

Tags: colors, terminal

It is possible to make some noisy rainbow with

```
LSCOLORS=GxBxhxDxhxhxhxhxhxcxcx
```

But is it possible to set colors for specific filetypes? E.g. for .js, .py, .html & other?

It's not working

```
LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=01;31:pi=40;33:js=01;35:html=01;35'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this for specific filetypes.

Use a globbing pattern: `LS_COLORS='*.js=01;35`